# Wierd Bug with Shooting Arrows

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

This is NOT a question based on aiming problems, it is another intrinsic bug that I seek the solution to.

Whenever I equip a bow and shoot (any type of arrow), even with a full charge, the arrow leaves the bow, only to land just a few inches away from my face. It has made bows quite useless in my game, as the arrows fired drop down as soon as they leave the bow. (This problem is on vanilla, i.e. NO MODS USED)

I completed the game, without even picking bows once, and thus did not notice the bug until now. Restarting the game sometimes fixes the issue, but is not a permanent solution. I have tried the unofficial patches and have updated syrim to its latest version, so it is not mended that way. Anyone up with a solution?